# Как ограничить прямой доступ к странице из адресной строки?

Tags: node.js

Делаю авторизацию с помощью passport.js. 
После того как пользователь зашел в свою страницу (localhost:3000/home), он может перейти на страницу админа набрав в адресной строке localhost:3000/admin. Какими средствами это можно запретить?
Ниже код на всякий случай:

**passport.js**

```
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('./database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);
connection.query("SET SESSION wait_timeout = 604800");

module.exports = function(passport) {

  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.id);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ? ", [id], function(err, rows){
      done(err, rows[0]);
    });
  });

  passport.use('local-login', new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField : 'username',
      passwordField : 'password',
      passReqToCallback : true
    },
    function(req, username, password, done) {
      connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?", [username], function(err, rows) {
        if(err)  return done(err);
        if(!rows.length) {return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'No user found.'));}
        if(!bcrypt.compareSync(password, rows[0].passwd))
          return done(null, false, req.flash('loginMessage', 'Oops! Wrong  password.'));
        return done(null, rows[0]);
      });
    })
  );
};
```

**router.js**

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

  app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index',  {message: req.flash('message')});
  });


  app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'
  // ,{
  //             successRedirect : 'home', // redirect to the secure profile section
  //             failureRedirect : '/', // redirect back to the signup page if there is an error
  //             failureFlash : true // allow flash messages
  //        }
    ),
          function(req, res) {
              console.log(req.body);
              if (req.body.remember) {
                req.session.cookie.maxAge = 10;
              } else {
                req.session.cookie.expires = false;
              }
              if(req.user.role==="admin") res.redirect('/admin');
              if(req.user.role==="user") res.redirect('/home');
              res.redirect('/');
  });

  app.get('/home', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('home', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
  });

  app.get('/admin', isLoggedIn, function(req, res) {
        res.render('admin', {
            user : req.user // get the user out of session and pass to template
        });
  });

  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {

    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
        return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the home page
    res.redirect('/');
  };





}
```

Comment: Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода" только для кода, который реально может быть выполнен в браузере. Для несамодостаточных кусков кода следует использовать блоки кода, форматируемые с помощью отступа в 4 пробела (Ctrl+K).

Comment: Думаю никак. GET запрос формируется клиентом, единственное что вы можете сделать это фильтроваться по какому-то секретному полю, генерируемому на сервере в Cookies и проверяя его на нужной странице. Вам проще проставить права пользователя и делать редирект на home если прав недостаточно.